# while installing rethinkdb i'm getting some socket error..how to overcome from that error

Tags: python-2.7

While installing rethinkdb, I'm get some socket error. How do I fix the error?

I tried:

```
$rethinkdb
error: TCP socket creation failed for port 29015: Address already in use.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Did you already install RethinkDB?**
I have this problem, when I installed the RethinkDB and I started the service. Then I followed the instructions on the meteor's docs, and when I typed the `rethinkdb` I got this error message too, because a **rethinkdb instance was already running**.

The **rethinkdb command will start a new rethinkdb instance!** Only one rethinkdb instance can runs.

You can stop rethinkdb with this command: `sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb stop`

Or you can check that you have a running rethinkdb with this url: `http://localhost:8080/`